# C program Create Array structure

Tags: c, arrays, struct, enums

I am trying to create an array library that allows the user
to use a single interface to create a 1-dimensional, 2-dimensional or 3-dimensional array of type int, char, float, or double.  My current approach seems too convoluted, I am wondering if I am on the right track, thanks.

```
typedef enum type
{
    CHAR, INT, FLOAT, DOUBLE
}

Type;

typedef struct array
{
    void *values;          // pointer to the data
    Type type;           // type of data
    int rank;            // # of dimensions (1, 2, and 3)
    int dimensions[3];   // a,b,c array dimensions
}

MultiArray;

MultiArray * array_init(int rank, int dims[], Type type); //init new Array

Array a;
a.ranking = ranking;
a.type = type;

switch (ranking)
{

    case 3:
    a.dimensions[0] = dimensions[0];
    a.dimensions[1] = dimensions[1];
    a.dimensions[2] = dimensions[2];

    switch (type)
    {

            case CHAR:
            values = new char**[dimensions[0]];

            for (int i = 0;i < dimensions[0];i++)
            {
                (((char***)values)[i]) *= new char * [dimensions[1]];

                for (int j = 0;j < dimensions[1];j++)
                    ((((char***)values)[i])*[j]) *= new char[dimensions[2]];
            }

            break;

            case INT:
            values = new int**[dimensions[0]];

            for (int i = 0;i < dimensions[0];i++)
            {
                (((int***)values)[i]) *= new int * [dimensions[1]];

                for (int j = 0;j < dimensions[1];j++)
                    ((((int***)values)[i])*[j]) *= new int[dimensions[2]];
            }

            break;

            case FLOAT:
            values = new float**[dimensions[0]];

            for (int i = 0;i < dimensions[0];i++)
            {
                (((float***)values)[i]) *= new float * [dimensions[1]];

                for (int j = 0;j < dimensions[1];j++)
                    ((((float***)values)[i])*[j]) *= new float[dimensions[2]];
            }

            break;

            case DOUBLE:
            values = new double**[dimensions[0]];

            for (int i = 0;i < dimensions[0];i++)
            {
                (((double***)values)[i]) *= new double * [dimensions[1]];

                for (int j = 0;j < dimensions[1];j++)
                    ((((double***)values)[i])*[j]) *= new double[dimensions[2]];
            }

            break;
    }

    break;

    case 2:
    a.dimensions[0] = dimensions[0];
    a.dimensions[1] = dimensions[1];

    switch (type)
    {

            case CHAR:
            values = new char * [dimensions[0]];

            for (int i = 0;i < dimensions[0];i++)
                (((char**)values)[i]) *= new char[dimensions[1]];

            break;

            case INT:
            values = new int * [dimensions[0]];

            for (int i = 0;i < dimensions[0];i++)
                (((int**)values)[i]) *= new int[dimensions[1]];

            break;

            case FLOAT:
            values = new float * [dimensions[0]];

            for (int i = 0;i < dimensions[0];i++)
                (((float**)values)[i]) *= new float[dimensions[1]];

            break;

            case DOUBLE:
            values = new double * [dimensions[0]];

            for (int i = 0;i < dimensions[0];i++)
                (((double**)values)[i]) *= new double[dimensions[1]];

            break;
    }

    break;

    case 1:
    a.dimensions[0] = dimensions[0];

    switch (type)
    {

            case CHAR:
            values = new char[dimensions[0]];
            break;

            case INT:
            values = new int[dimensions[0]];
            break;

            case FLOAT:
            values = new float[dimensions[0]];
            break;

            case DOUBLE:
            values = new double[dimensions[0]];
            break;
    }

    break;
}

return a;

void display_array(Array * arr); // prints Array
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you mean to tag C++ or C? If C, you want to change those "new"s to malloc.

Comment: @CharlieBurns he is using C. Any way, will be nice to know the motives for this - maybe we can simplify the code.

Comment: Some indentation would be nice, and at least make an effort to get it to compile.

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to be able to perform different operations on multi-dimensional arrays, like finding the minimum element or max element or summing the elements.  So mallocing is what I'm missing? thanks.  Also, I did not include a main function because that would just contain whatever I needed to test the functions.

Comment: Roughly you are on the right track. It won't extend to an Nd array of course. And since values is a 1d array, you will need to access it with an expression that is a function of the indices and the sizes.

Comment: If you make `dimensions` a simple integer, won't that make your lookups easier? Each element can then be accessed using `[dimensions*Size[x])`, where `Size` is an array of sizes for each of your basic types. You'd still need separate cases, though, because you need to cast the `value` array to the correct type. If you make it a union, you don't need that (you still need a switch to select the proper union *member*).